# Documentation for Apache's Parquet Java API?

Tags: parquet

I would like to use Apache's parquet-mr project to read/write Parquet files programmatically with Java.  I can't seem to find any documentation for how to use this API (aside from going through the source code and seeing how it's used) -- just wondering if any such documentation exists?

Comment: Better go through the unit tests, I couldn't find any documents yet. :)

Comment: Mean while you can go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42078757/is-it-possible-to-read-and-write-parquet-using-java-without-a-dependency-on-hado/42224290#42224290) as a sample.

Comment: Thanks @Krishas, that's a start

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a blog article about reading parquet files (http://www.jofre.de/?p=1459) and came up with the following solution that even is capable of reading INT96 fields.

You need the following maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-hadoop</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The code basically is:

```java
public class Main {

    private static Path path = new Path("file:\\C:\\Users\\file.snappy.parquet");

    private static void printGroup(Group g) {

        int fieldCount = g.getType().getFieldCount();
        for (int field = 0; field < fieldCount; field++) {
            int valueCount = g.getFieldRepetitionCount(field);

            Type fieldType = g.getType().getType(field);
            String fieldName = fieldType.getName();

            for (int index = 0; index < valueCount; index++) {
                if (fieldType.isPrimitive()) {
                    System.out.println(fieldName + " " + g.getValueToString(field, index));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        try {
            ParquetMetadata readFooter = ParquetFileReader.readFooter(conf, path, ParquetMetadataConverter.NO_FILTER);
            MessageType schema = readFooter.getFileMetaData().getSchema();
            ParquetFileReader r = new ParquetFileReader(conf, path, readFooter);

            PageReadStore pages = null;
            try {
                while (null != (pages = r.readNextRowGroup())) {
                    final long rows = pages.getRowCount();
                    System.out.println("Number of rows: " + rows);

                    final MessageColumnIO columnIO = new ColumnIOFactory().getColumnIO(schema);
                    final RecordReader<Group> recordReader = columnIO.getRecordReader(pages, new GroupRecordConverter(schema));
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                        final Group g = recordReader.read();
                        printGroup(g);

                        // TODO Compare to System.out.println(g);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                r.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading parquet file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the recursive call when you try to System out values? It seems to me that if the type is not primitive, the code does nothing about that field.

Comment: But do you think we should use classes from org.apache.parquet.example package for reading parquet files?

Answer (score 6):

You can find the docs at this link: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.parquet/parquet-column/1.10.0

Use the upper left dropdown [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8iqH.png) to navigate

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is a bit sparse and the code is somewhat tersely documented. I found ORC much easier to work with if that's an option for you.

The code snippet below converts a Parquet file to CSV with a header row using the Avro interface - it will fail if you have the INT96 (Hive timestamp) type in the file (an Avro interface limitation) and decimals come out as a byte array.

Make sure you use version 1.9.0 or higher of the parquet-avro library otherwise the logging is a bit of a mess.

```
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out), "ASCII"));

        ParquetReader<GenericRecord> reader = AvroParquetReader.<GenericRecord>builder(path).build();

        Schema sc = null;
        List<Field> fields = null;
        for(long i = 0; i < lines; i++)  {
            GenericRecord result = reader.read();
            if(result == null)  {
                break;
            }

            if(i == 0)  {
                sc = result.getSchema();
                fields = sc.getFields();
                if(header)  {       // print header out?
                    for(int j = 0; j < fields.size(); j++)  {
                        if(j != 0)  {
                            out.write(",");
                        }
                        out.write(fields.get(j).name());
                    }
                    out.newLine();
                }
            }

            for(int j = 0; j < fields.size(); j++)  {
                if(j != 0)  {
                    out.write(",");
                }
                Object o = result.get(j);
                if(o != null)  {
                    String v = o.toString();
                    if(!v.equals("null"))  {
                        out.write("\"" + v + "\"");
                    }
                }
            }
            out.newLine();
        }
        out.flush();
        reader.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @FatFreddie, this is helpful but I'm really looking for documentation for the parquet-mr library, not parquet-avro.

Comment: As I understand it, Parquet-mr is the Java interface to Parquet. Within that you have a variety of interfaces...

 parquet-avro
 parquet-thrift
 parquet-protobuf
 etc

There is also the "simple" interface used by parquet-tools (the CLI utility) - search the repo for CatCommand.java.

The simple interface is easy enough to get going but as far as I can tell, doesn't support read schemas and I've seen comments that it was only intended as an example interface so I stopped using that.

The Avro interface does support read schema and generally works quite well but doesn't support INT96.

Answer (score 0):

This is an addition to @padmalcom's answer. The code on that answer was just lacking the recursive operation for nested values. Instead I am returning a JSONObject and it is up to the developer how to print it etc. I am using below function instead of his printGroup() function. (Thanks for the original inspiration)

```
private static JSONObject convertParquetGroupToJSONObject(final Group g) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        int fieldCount = g.getType().getFieldCount();
        for (int field = 0; field < fieldCount; field++) {
            int valueCount = g.getFieldRepetitionCount(field);
            Type fieldType = g.getType().getType(field);
            String fieldName = fieldType.getName();
            for (int index = 0; index < valueCount; index++) {
                if (fieldType.isPrimitive()) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject.put(fieldName, g.getValueToString(field, index));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else{
                    try {
                        jsonObject.put(fieldName, convertParquetGroupToJSONObject(g.getGroup(field, index)));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
```

Comment: FWIW, this doesn't handle lists or some more complex nested structures. I eventually ended up using AvroParquetReader, which handles this internally - https://github.com/benwatson528/intellij-avro-parquet-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/hadoopathome/intellij/viewer/fileformat/ParquetFileReader.java